# Can jSerialComm use the UART RX and TX pins on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: serial, java

I made a PCB board that can handle measurements and control from a web application made in Java (Vaadin) and I want to connect the RX and TX pins of that PCB board to my Raspberry Pi 4B.

I tried to connect RX -> TX and RT -> RX between the PCB board and the Raspberry Pi 4B. Then I'm using jSerialComm library for communication in Java. But it did not work for me.

**Question**

Is jSerialComm library only made for "USB"-communication and not using the RX and TX pins as well in Raspberry Pi?

Else, my PCB board works well with a FTDI232 chip between the PCB board and the Raspberry Pi USB port.

https://github.com/DanielMartensson/OpenSourceLogger

Comment: Without details of what you have done it is impossible to answer. It is certainly possible to connect serial in any language. Have you enabled serial on the Pi?

Comment: @Milliways Yes I have enabled. But perhaps jSerialComm is a USB library, and not an UART library?

Answer (score 1):

Dan
What you may need is one if these boards
https://atlas-scientific.com/ezo-accessories/basic-usb-to-serial-converter/
They connect to the usb on the pi and then to serial on your custom board
I have used these in the past, and they work great
Dan

Comment: I solved the issue. jSerialComm can use the RX and TX pins if you using `ttyS0`